# Where can I find the declaration of HOST_E_CLRNOTAVAILABLE (type HRESULT) constant?

Tags: c#, c++, clr, msdn

Could anyone, please, help me to find the header file, which contains the declaration of HRESULTs returned by `ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()` function. The compiler doesn't see the values documented in MSDN: `HOST_E_CLRNOTAVAILABLE`, `HOST_E_NOT_OWNER` etc. Note, that `<MSCorEE.h>` is included.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those codes are in CorError.h. Just `#include <corerror.h>` and they'll be available.

Answer (score 4):

They are defined in [corerror.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/pal/prebuilt/inc/corerror.h).

Comment: The link is dead, but the corerror.h can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/pal/prebuilt/inc/corerror.h

Comment: @kkCosmo: Thanks for the hint. Fixed